# ServiceBusTrigger: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus'

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Any thoughts on what might be causing this exception ?

Exception during runtime resolution of assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c': 'System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.AppDomain cannot be cast to [B]System.AppDomain. Type A originates from 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'.

I have created a class library with .net Standard 2.0 and added 2 azure functions one for httpTrigger & other for serviceBusTrigger.

httpTrigger is working as expected however serviceBusTrigger is crashing with below error [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeYDO.png).

ServiceBusTrigger.cs :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

namespace TriggerCore
{
    public static class SBTrigger
    {
        static SBTrigger()
        {
        }
        public static void Run(Message message)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

function.json :

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "accessRights": "manage",
      "name": "message"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../TriggerCore.dll",
  "entryPoint": "TriggerCore.SBTrigger.Run"
}
```

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus version 1.0.0

NetStandard.Library version 2.0.0

Comment: Looks like a version conflict. Give a try to Functions SDK-based project (with attributes and auto-generated `function.json`).

Comment: thanks for your help @Mikhail. Instead of Functions SDK-based project which is .net full framework, I would like to go with NetStandard.Library version 2.0.0. Let me know if you have any pointers.

Comment: Version 1.0.5 of SDK should support .NET Standard, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614307/1171619

Answer (score 0):

The new .NET Core runtime doesn't yet support ServiceBus trigger. We're still in the process of migrating that and some of the other extensions to .NET Core. See tracking issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1329).