# Azure function, .Net core 2.0, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, azure-functions

How can I use Azure functions with target framework .net Core, I am able to use framework 4.6.x but not .net core.

I tried to change net461 to .net core but does not work.
I could not find anything on Microsoft site.

Any leads please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target .NET Core 2.0 with Azure Functions in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608959/target-net-core-2-0-with-azure-functions-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new project: File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Cloud -> Azure Functions and then you get a window in which you can choose target framework, as shown in the photo below:

[image]

For that to work you nned to have Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools  - you can install it through Tools -> Extensions and Updates.

Comment: Hi Maciej, I can create azure functions using .Net core after update. thank you.